# extern class variable causes compiler error

Tags: c++, class

I have a header file head.hh containing these defintions (I am trying to implement the singleton pattern):

```
#ifndef HEAD_HH
#define HEAD_HH

class X
{
private:
  X() : i(0) {}

public:
  static X &instance()
  {
    static X x;
    return x;
  }

  int i;

};

#endif
```

My implementation impl.cc looks like this:

```
#include "head.hh"

X &iks = X::instance();

iks.i = 17;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  return 0;
}
```

I think that this code is correct, but I get the compiler error (using g++)

```
impl.cc:5:1: error: ‘iks’ does not name a type
 iks.i = 17;
```

Could anyone tell me why I can create a reference from the static ::instance() but not use it for anything? (If I comment in the fifth line everything works fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put an assignment at global scope. It must be part of a function, for instance:

```
// ...

iks.i = 17; // ERROR! Assignment not in the scope of a function

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    iks.i = 17;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^ This is OK, we're inside a function body
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. I just hid the assignment in the constructor because I would prefer it if everything is already done when I call main...

Comment: @hfhc2: Here you did not hid the assignment in the constructor though, you have put it at global scope. If you want to initialize `i` to the value of `17`, just replace the `0` in the member initialization with `17`

Comment: Well, this was only an example, I am actually working on something a little more complex, but RAII does the trick in that case too...